# Python IRC bot won't exist from chat when receiving "!quit" command

Tags: python, irc, bots

This irc bot is not complicated at all. I am just having trouble with a couple lines of code. Basically I added this to the end of the while statement:

```
 if "!quit" in msg:
        sys.exit()
```

Basically what this does is when someone types !quit in irc the script will log the bot out of irc.

The rest of the script (very short) can be found here:

http://pastebin.com/055CcWZf

Can someone tell me why the last bit is not working. When I am in irc I enter "!quit" but the bot does not respond at all.

Comment: What does Ping-pong part of your script do? Does your script execute it?

Comment: When the script detects a Ping from server it sends pong to avoid a ping timeout.

Comment: can your PING message contain "!quit" in it? Because your script looks like it is expecting it to be part of this message.

Answer (score 0):

in original script "if !quit" statement is within "if ping" statement.

```
if "PING" in msg:
    s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % msg[1])
if "!quit" in msg:
    sys.exit()
```

I think this should be correct