# Python IRC bot won't exist from chat when receiving “.quit” command

Tags: python, irc, bots

So I asked this a few days ago and the response I got was to

This irc bot is not complicated at all. I am just having trouble with a couple lines of code. Basically I added this to the end of the while statement:
    if ".quit" in readbuffer:
            print "Found quit command"
            sys.exit()

Basically what this does is when someone types .quit in irc the script will log the bot out of irc.

The rest of the script (very short) can be found here:

http://www.paestebin.org/view/vrsqdnyjpss3rctko2woabuul8

Can someone tell me why the last bit is not working. When I am in irc I enter ".quit" but the bot does not respond at all. I asked for help here a few days ago and the only response I got was telling me that the .quit statement was within the ping statement. I fixed that but still the bot is not responding. I have absolutely no idea where to from here. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python IRC bot won't exist from chat when receiving "!quit" command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975893/python-irc-bot-wont-exist-from-chat-when-receiving-quit-command)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `readbuffer` is empty, you want to look in `temp[0]` instead:

```
if ".quit" in temp[0]:
    print "Found quit command"
    sys.exit()
```

Looking at your bot, there's a few other things that you may want to change, like not making it issue a `JOIN` command after *every line of input that it reads*. The `PONG` response also needs to include the sender, so it should look like this: `PONG <your host> <PING body>` instead of what you're doing now: `PONG <PING body>`.

Comment: @ArnoldGreenberg You should accept the answer then, otherwise your question will continue to show up as unanswered.